# how to add meta for order in woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, post-meta

I'm creating a custom plugin for my website.

In some part of this plugin I need to store extra meta in wp_postmeta for each orders.

Comment: When you want to add it? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

by this action can add extra meta to order
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',function( $order_id, $posted ){
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_custom_meta_key', 'my data' );
} , 10, 2);

**$order_id** is the id of the order, which is stored as a custom post type

**$posted** is all the data from $_POST